# PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare [ By using php -l in terminal]

Tags: php, syntax

I wrote the php script and gone for syntax check via terminal `php -l my_filepath`, then suddenly found fatal error `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare` even my code executing successfully.

also check on other system with same script but it's show `No syntax errors detected`, 
so where i am going wrong.

common_functions_helper.php

```
<?php
   function hex2bin() {
     // code here
   }
```

After check syntax error in terminal

```
$ php -l application/helpers/common_functions_helper.php
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare hex2bin() in application/helpers/common_functions_helper.php on line 1013
Errors parsing application/helpers/common_functions_helper.php
```

even though function is not re-declare any where throughout the code base

Comment: Can you post the code to pastebin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hex2bin` is PHP library function available for PHP >= 5.4.0: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php. Pick another name.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no code posted at the time of this reply, let's make some assumptions here and note that *php -l* looks at the whole file while executing a php script in cases might report a run-time error only if respective statement causing the error is executed.

For example, if what you are redeclaring is within an *if*-statement then executing the php script may not result in an error if the code flow does not go through the code within the *if* statement (e.g. if there is an *include*)

The suggestion would be to find and look at the line numbers causing the error and fix it because the problem exists even if you do not see it when executing the script in the environment and instance that you did.

Furthermore because this error may be common when '*include*' is used you can use '*include_once*' instead of '*include*' and the problem may be fixed.